# What is a good resource for how American women talked in the 1940s?

Tags: discussion, resources, online-resources, research-effort

You can find some pretty good diaries for men, from the war. But I'm not sure what a reliable source is for female American vernacular of the '40s.

Movies of the time sanitize conversations, and use mid-Atlantic speech, so they're a questionable source.

Is there any resource used to teach students of linguistics or history about how people talked in the 1940s? I'm sure there's something present day Hollywood uses, to research accents and dialects.

Thanks for any direction on this.

Comment: Search theatrical plays from that era, I would think that playwrights sought to reproduce authentic exchanges between characters. Best avoid musicals and large Broadway productions though

Comment: There's a list of playwrights from 1945 in this paper https://www.academia.edu/12722466/post_WWII_American_Dramatists

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you exceptionally much!